# Valgrind and global variables

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm running valgrind to look for memory leaks. I have alloc'd two global variables in the main function; then, at the end of `main` I free both, but Valgrind keeps writing:

```
==18311== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==18311==    at 0x4025BD3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==18311==    by 0x804A30C: main (application.c:730)
==18311== 
==18311== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==18311==    at 0x4025BD3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==18311==    by 0x804A31D: main (application.c:731)
```

Leak summary:

```
==18311== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18311==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==18311==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18311==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18311==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18311==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Why I can't free these two variables?

**Edit**

```
someList *something; *something_else;
```

The struct used has two fields of type `char *` and a field `someList *next`. 
Later there's a lot of code. A few threads are going to add/edit/delete objects using this two variables.

```
something -> object 1 -> ... -> object n
something_else -> object 1 -> ... -> object m
```

Where `->` means that `something->next = object 1`, and `object k` are all instances of `someList *`.

Near the end of the application, I freed every field of each `object k` element. Then, in the last part:

```
free(something);
free(something_else);
```

It's possible that I forgot to free a field of an object. Can this cause the behavior I'm having here?

I hope it's clearer, now.

Comment: Is the part of the code where you free them executed? An early return from the main function might skip it.

Comment: @CodeInChaos yes: the code is executed. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `malloc()` call you typically need a corresponding `free()` call, in order to avoid memory leaks. For optimal memory usage, you should `free()` each allocated memory block as soon as possible after being done with it.

In your case, you have two `malloc()` calls in `application.c:730` and `application.c:731`, for which there is no `free()` call made by the time your program terminates. Therefore, the memory blocks allocated there are not freed. This causes a memory leak that `Valgrind` detects and reports.

Unless you provide us with some code and/or more information on your program there is no way for us to help you more.

EDIT:

There are two interesting lines in your `Valgrind` output:

```
==18311==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
...
==18311==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

You have definitely "lost" two memory blocks and there no pointers to them at the time your program terminates. This means that the pointers to these two blocks were in fact overwritten or otherwise lost their value during the course of your program.

A common cause of this issue is storing the result of two `malloc()` calls to the same pointer without an intermediate `free()` call. Another possible cause is a changed pointer value due to pointer arithmetic operations - `Valgrind` makes an effort to detect some of these cases, but it is not always successful, depending on your code.

Comment: Keep in mind the first sentence of this answer is about valgrind's idea of memory leaks and not the user's. In any user's eye, a long-lived program which never frees anything until just before exit has a huge memory leak, while in valgrind's eyes is has no leak. Conversely, a one-off command line program that does its task and that never frees anything has no memory leaks in any user's eyes, but it does in valgrind's.

Comment: @R..: I rephrased the answer a bit to somewhat cover this point.

Comment: So from what I gather after reading this, is global variables DO NOT need to free'd, is that a safe assumption? Say with a declaration of `char mychar[80];` <- located outside of main (global)

Comment: @SSHThis: The space used for global variables *cannot* be freed. Keep in mind, though, that global variables could also be *pointers* to dynamically allocated objects that do need to be freed themselves...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're deallocating all of your variables? Valgrind says you're not.

Try and make your code slim and post it here, or run some more debugging.